# Facebook birthday sync only working for some contacts

Tags: macos, ios, calendar, facebook

I recently noticed that only a couple of my contacts' birthdays show up on my calendar on OS X.  For instance, I have four friends with birthdays today, but only one is on my calendar.  I tried deleting and re-adding my Facebook account but notice no difference.

I'm getting the exact same behavior on my iPhone.

Maybe this isn't a Mac issue.  Did Facebook change the way its sync works?

Comment: Are you getting any Facebook data *other* than the birthday for those contacts (avatar, etc.)? If not, it's possible the OS X Facebook integration is failing to match those contacts with their Facebook accounts (they could be using different email addresses on Facebook than you have in Contacts, for example).

Comment: @DanJ - When I click on the Facebook section of the Contacts App, I only see the friends whose birthdays are showing up.  It looks like Facebook isn't grabbing any of their information.  Is this just a privacy setting they've enabled?

Answer (score 1):

Facebook has an option for friends to Opt OUT of their birthdays being displayed to other people. So if I had you on FaceBook and I turned the option off to display to you what my Birthday is, the it won't sync to your Calendar.

Comment: If I log into Facebook I see those 4 birthdays (that's the only way I know it's their birthday).  Does this option only prevent outside services (ie OS X Calendar) from showing the birthday?